# how to give time duration for gif image in nativescript-Angular app

Tags: nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular

I am using nativescript-gif plugin for loading gif images on app component because of  component routing to another component without showing gif image how to show gif image first then routing should happen

Comment: Use a GridLayout to place a GIF view above page router outlet, so irrespective of navigation you can have the GIF view playing as long as you want. Once you are done, just remove the GIF the page below should be visible.

Comment: how to use start() and stop() api function from nativescript-gif plugin in angular not able get any code how to use it

Comment: <Gif #playGif  src="~/images/logogif.gif" height="100%" ></Gif>                                                                                                             
  @ViewChild("playGif") gifRef: ElementRef;
      this.gifRef.nativeElement.start();  ------> undefined how to use start()  and stop() function here

Comment: When exactly you are accessing the start method?

Comment: I am calling start method inside ngafterviewinit